# AJAX target file wont show data for upload processing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a piece of code which allows me to control several AJAX requests. I stored this in a function I am expanding, especially due to the fact i am now trying to control an upload. Where i bump into, is the fact that my data is not shown when i call up on the upload functionality. Now i am aware that i have to use certain ajax parameters to get result, which i added, but still no luck for me.

At first, on submit, I store data in an array, before handling it in the function.

```
$('body').on('submit', '#import-propperties', function(e) {
    
        var vars = {
                
            url : domain + '/core/ajax/import.php',
        
            form : 'prep-preview',
            
            files : new FormData(this),
            
            process : false,
            
            contenttype: 'application/json',
            
        }
    
        datahandle(vars);
        
        return false;
        
    });
```

This i push towards my datahandle as you see. The data handle is the AJAX call.

```
function datahandle(vars){

        
        if(!('process' in vars)) {

            vars.process = true;
            
        } 
        
        if(!('contenttype' in vars)) {

            vars.contenttype = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
            
        }

        if('files' in vars) {

            var r = vars.files;

        } else {
            
            var r = {}
            
            $.extend( true, r, vars );  
            
        }           
            
        console.log(r);

    
        $.ajax({
             
            url: vars.url,
            
            type: "post",
           
            data: r,
            
            processData: vars.process,

            contentType: vars.contenttype,
            
            success: function(data){
                
                ...........
```

To elaborate, what i do in this function is i check first if i deal with files or not, if not i do not add for example the `processData` parameter and the `contentType` parameter of AJAX, so i let the if / else statments sort the defaults out. Then i get to the data, and I think within here lies my problem. If no files tag is used, i push all data in `variable r`, and let that go towards the server. For random key/value pairs this works great, but as soon as i want to use the files, i dont get anything back from the server.

I do see the request going and see data in it, but when i do an output say with `$_FILES` it returns blank to me.

[image: see request]

When i look in the response i see the following

[image: Response]

I am not sure what is going on, but can anyone help me on this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the content type as  `application/json` is incorrect, since you are uploading multipart form data. To accomplish this with jQuery.ajax you have to set the content type to false.

```
var vars = {
        
    url : domain + '/core/ajax/import.php',

    form : 'prep-preview',
    
    files : new FormData(this),
    
    process : false,
    
    contenttype: false,
    
}
```

Comment: ack!! been gawking all over this whole evening!!!! thank you. I thought i had set it to false, but i think i copied something wrong over and put it in my array! you have my thanks!!!!